# Editing text above downloadable products

Tags: commerce

I am trying to change the intro text above a form for downloadable products in Drupal Commerce, it needs a privacy policy link. I didn't create the website and I can't find where the text is generated.

I've tried a plugin that integrates a checkbox, but this website doesn't use commerce checkout. I've been trying for hours adding fields, fieldgroups, modules and what not.. but I can't even find where the intro text is! I'm used to Wordpress, Joomla, Grav and Open cart - complete Drupal newb though.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what steps I should take?

Comment: Please don't include links to your website to demonstrate an issue which hopefully doesn't persist. As soon as you find a way to fix your issue this link's value drops to zero for all future readers. Please try to explain your issue with the help of use cases, screenshots and code snippets instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we won't be able to help you solve this. The interface on that site for purchasing products has been custom developed for you, and it's likely that the text in there is hard coded in a site-specific customizations module. If you have access to the codebase, you can confirm this by searching all the files (via a command line tool called grep) for a unique phrase like *"UV and EB"*.

Comment: This is an useful comment. But it's not an answer. Please don't use the answering function to drop comments.

Comment: I'm not new here. The only possible answer to this question - "tell me what steps I should take" - is what I've described. In reality, it's just not a suitable type of question for this forum, and I'd be happy for it to be closed out.

Comment: Sure, then drop a comment and flag it. No offense. :)

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't know that I posted in the wrong category/forum. Regardless, thanks for the help. At least I now know where to look (not in the site, but in the files).